# I am using Vonage (Tokbox) API for video calling. I have generated session and token but stream id is not getting created

Tags: codeigniter

I am using Vonage (Tokbox) API for video calling. Integrating Vonage using codeigniter.
I have generated session and token but stream id is not getting created. What is happening getStream($sessionId, $streamId) method of the OpenTok\OpenTok class in this class but stream id is not getting generated.
my code is:

```
$opentok = new OpenTok($this->config->item('opentok_key'), $this->config->item('opentok_secret'));


        // Create a session that attempts to use peer-to-peer streaming:
        $session = $opentok->createSession();

        // A session that uses the OpenTok Media Router, which is required for archiving:
        $session = $opentok->createSession(array( 'mediaMode' => MediaMode::ROUTED ));

        // A session with a location hint:
        // $session = $opentok->createSession(array( 'location' => '12.34.56.78' ));

        // An automatically archived session:
        $sessionOptions = array(
            'archiveMode' => ArchiveMode::ALWAYS,
            'mediaMode' => MediaMode::ROUTED
        );
        $session = $opentok->createSession($sessionOptions);


        // Store this sessionId in the database for later use
        $sessionId = $session->getSessionId();


        // Generate a Token from just a sessionId (fetched from a database)
        $token = $opentok->generateToken($sessionId);
        // Generate a Token by calling the method on the Session (returned from createSession)
        $token = $session->generateToken();

        // Set some options in a token
        $token = $session->generateToken(array(
            'role'       => Role::MODERATOR,
            'expireTime' => time()+(7 * 24 * 60 * 60), // in one week
            'data'       => 'name=Johnny',
            'initialLayoutClassList' => array('focus')
        ));



        // Get stream info from just a sessionId (fetched from a database)
        $stream = $opentok->getStream($sessionId, $streamId);
        // echo "<pre>"; print_r($stream); exit();

        // Stream properties
        $stream->id; // string with the stream ID
        $stream->videoType; // string with the video type
        $stream->name; // string with the name
        $stream->layoutClassList; // array with the layout class list
```

Answer (score 1):

`getStream($sessionId, $streamId)` requires `streamId` as a parameter which you have to pass in. That method will not generate it for you.

You only created the session but you have to either publish a stream or subscribe to an existing stream. If you don't want to publish any streams as a `publisher`, you will have to listen to `streamCreated` event to subscribe to other streams. Take a look at the dev doc for all stream events: [StreamEvent](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/StreamEvent.html)

Answer (score 0):

From this event you have to generate /make stram id and pass it to getStream(session ID,steamId) metnod.

```
session.on("streamCreated", function (event) {
    console.log("New stream in the session: " + event.stream.streamId);
});
// Replace with a valid token:
session.connect(token);
```

so event.stream.streamId will give you the required thing.

Reference :
https://developer.vonage.com/en/video/guides/subscribe-streams/detect-streams?source=video